# can any one initiate the requirement for an i3wm desktop distribution in ubuntu - I need a seperate distrobution in ubuntu for i3wm

Tags: boot

i3wm is very authentic distribution to work with multitasking...I been finding a distribution in Ubuntu solely supporting i3wm, there is a such distribution in fedora fedora i3 spin, that is a good option, but i been looking for a distribution from Ubuntu for the i3wm desktop environment.

I think this mail will reach Ubuntu core team.

Comment: You could try just installing the i3 package, and selecting that while logging in. There are no "distribution in Ubuntu solely supporting" even for other DEs. I have Ubuntu not Kubuntu installed, yet I'm still using KDE. Talking about non-supported distro is off-topic. No, it's not the case that "this mail will reach Ubuntu core team." It only reached some community volunteers, and you might have better luck on the forums

Answer (score 0):

Different flavors are created by the community, not by Canonical engineers.

Nobody will do all the work for you.

The first step is to recruit a group of like-minded i3wm fans, and to collectively decide to share the technical work.

You don't need to ask anybody for permission.

Comment: you do if you want to use the Ubuntu name.